# How to use FlowRouter to parse any given url?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I want to parse an iframe URL using `FlowRouter.getQueryparams()` instead of using `window.location.href.split()`. I have tried looking into documents, but all it talks about is passing parameters and in-app routing. Is there a way to pass URL like : `http://localhost:3000/?id="Awx34R56YUND"&userId="QP90pr5f"` to Flowrouter and get the parameters like `FlowRouter.getQueryparams('id')` and `FlowRouter.getQueryparams('userId')`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get query parameters in a URL, see this example below

```
// route def: /apps/:appId
// url: /apps/this-is-my-app?show=yes&color=red

var color = FlowRouter.getQueryParam("color");
console.log(color); // prints "red"
```

source:
[Documentation](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#flowroutergetqueryparamquerystringkey)

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. It always returns me undefined.

Comment: try this http://localhost:3000/?id=Awx34R56YUND&userId=QP90pr5f, I noticed you included them in quotes